# boost::asio::deadline_timer cancel() method is not calling timer handler

Tags: c++, boost, https, timer, boost-asio

**Boost 1.69**

Hi. I'm trying to make a class to do https that does requests but also has a timeout for error checking.

I'm using the boost beast functions for the https (which works fine) and Im using the deadline_timer class to set the timer

I set up the https request and the timer to run on the the same IO_context. The idea is that if the timeout happens I want to throw an error and stop execution of the IO context or if the https works correctly I want to stop the timer.

I'm trying to use the `cancel()` method to stop the timer and invoke the timeout handle as per documentation states

> This function forces the completion of any pending asynchronous wait operations against the timer. The handler for each cancelled operation will be invoked with the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error code

However the timer handler is never called. How do I do to call the timer handler when I cancel the timer?

Here is some code:

```
    /* Set up timeout timer and start it */
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer{query->ioc,boost::posix_time::seconds(TIMEOUT_HTTPS)};
    timer.async_wait(std::bind(&HttpsCom::on_timeout, this, std::placeholders::_1, query));

    // Look up the domain name
    std::cout << "Making the request..." << std::endl;
    tcp::resolver resolver{query->ioc};
    resolver.async_resolve(host, port, std::bind(&HttpsCom::on_resolve,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2, query));

    query->ioc.run();

 if (latestError == HTTPS_SUCCESS){
      std::size_t test = timer.cancel();
      std::cout << test << std::endl; // Timer gets cancel as test = 1 
}
```

This is my timer handler

```
void HttpsCom::on_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::shared_ptr<HTTPSQueryStruct_t> query){
  std::cout << "Timeout" << std::endl;
  }
```

And this is my shutdown handler (HTTPS was succesful)

```
void HttpsCom::on_shutdown(boost::system::error_code ec, std::shared_ptr<HTTPSQueryStruct_t> query){
  std::cout << "on_shutdown()" << std::endl;

  // boost::ignore_unused(ec);
  std::cerr << "on_shutdown" << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;    

  /* If we get here the connection was closed gracefully */
  setLatestErrorCode(HTTPS_SUCCESS);
  query->ioc.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Seems that stopping the ioc just deletes or somehow forgets the queued handlers. Therefore when calling the timer.cancel() function after stopping ioc wont take you anywhere as it already forgot the handler.